# programmatically find the repository URL of a project

Tags: eclipse

I want to programmatically find the repository to which the given project in eclipse is connected to. 
I have 3 java projects in eclipse, Project A -- connected to svn repository - url - svn://localhost/prjA , Project B -- svn://localhost/prjB and Project C -- svn://localhost/prjC. Given "projectA" -- i want to get the url it is connect to.Please suggest a way to get this information...

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. What language?

Comment: Have you installed any svn client extensions to eclipse like svnkit or subclipse?

Comment: How did you checkout the projects?  If you did it in eclipse through `import>new svn project...` you would be able to see the repo URL next to the project in the file manager.

Comment: yes i have it....I am writing an eclipse plugin, through which, given a  project (IProject object), I need to get the URL of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/team_provider_repository.htm) for information about implementing what's called a repository provider for Eclipse.  There's a repository provider for each version control "product": there's one for Git, one for SVN, etc.

Basically there are two times when this provider gets called - when an Eclipse project gets associated with a provider and when the project becomes disassociated from the provider.  It's at the first point where such things as the repository URL get stashed away in a provider-specific means.

To answer your question, you'll have to know how the provider(s) associated with the projects stash the association metadata away.  That's how and where your code will look to get the info you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will answer your question.

```
IResource res = ...
ISVNLocalResource svnResource = SVNWorkspaceRoot.getSVNResourceFor(res);
try {
    ISVNRepositoryLocation repository = svnResource.getRepository();
    System.out.println(repository.getUrl().toString());
} catch (SVNClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Tim.